# Mulltisite Manager - How to find out which site users come from

Tags: members, member-details, multiple-sites

I  am using multisite (MSM) and i want to show user listing for different site for admin. How can admin see the users list according to site.

For eg: -

I am having 5 sites (named as Site-A, Site-B, Site-C, site-D and Site-E) 
and  i have created new member group for each site from admin CMS (Members->Member Groups->Create a Member Group) as below:

Member Group Name for Site-A is user-A and

Member Group Name for Site-B is user-B and

Member Group Name for Site-C is user-C and

Member Group Name for Site-D is user-D and

Member Group Name for Site-E is user-E.

i have implemented login/registration functionality for each site.

Now Users can register  from the above sites.

But in admin CMS, It is showing all users for all site on a page (Members->View Members).

Here how can i know the user comes from which site ?

Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created separate member groups for each site then can you not simply use the filter dropdowns to show each group and see which members are in it?

[image]

UPDATE

If you are using different registration forms for each site then you could create a hidden field containing the site name and have that info stored in a custom profile field. Then it won't matter if the user activates the account or not.

Comment: but initially Member Group type is "Pending" 
then how can i know ?

Comment: Well at that point they aren't actually members since they haven't validated their account. But I'll update my answer with a possible solution for any new members. You won't be able to tell where historic members came from.

Comment: then what is the solution for this ? 
any idea?

Comment: means when more users registered them from different sites then 
from admin CMS, how can admin know which user comes from which site ?
 Because initially they all (who have registered themselves from different sites) are in pending states ?
Any idea? or any other solution ?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: then how can i see user listing for a particular site if i use custom profile field.
it is not showing members for a site.
any idea ?